# Background-image fade into another through background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Snippet of code: https://jsfiddle.net/foy4m43j/

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/hH9IWA0.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

From here, I'd like to produce this sort of effect using it's `background-position` to include a fade and the new colour (black lines to show the direction we're moving):
[image: Crossfade of background positions]

Example images (please excuse the bad exports):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hH9IWA0.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Qp1jE07.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/TfvFfPq.png]

Is this possible through jQuery or CSS? I'm scratching my head on how I can do this with `background-position` and multiple images.

This is my awful attempt so far. I don't understand why the gradient is going the other direction and I'm not sure how to make the yellow repeat itself to the right X axis only:
https://jsfiddle.net/foy4m43j/1/

I hope I'm clear enough. I can't find any other questions similar apart from one that had no response.

Comment: You can move something like: https://jsfiddle.net/foy4m43j/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use CSS gradient. By far the best solution, and it is easy to make:**
[www.colorzilla.com](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Thanks but my final usage won't be with gradients but with images.